# Jest toMatchObject throws TypeError

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I'm using Jest to test my node app and the following case verifies that some data has been added to the DB (consider `DB` logic works all right):

```
it("should add empty string hooks if none added", async () => {
    const item = { type: "type" };

    await DB.insert({ item });

    const fetch = await DB.fetch({ type: "type" });

    expect(fetch.data.items).toHaveLength(1);
    expect(typeof fetch.data.items[0]).toEqual("object");
    expect(fetch.data.items[0]).toMatchObject({
        ...item,
        preHook: "",
        postHook: "",
        otherField: expect.anything(),
        // ... other fields created by DB might go here
    });
});
```

I get this results when running `npm test`:

```
FAIL  test/server/server.test.jsal
  ● Database › Items › should add empty string hooks if none added

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined

      236 |             expect(fetch.data.items).toHaveLength(1);
      237 |             expect(typeof fetch.data.items[0]).toEqual("object");
    > 238 |             expect(fetch.data.items[0]).toMatchObject({
          |                                             ^
      239 |                 ...item,
      240 |                 preHook: "",
      241 |                 postHook: ""

      at _callee17$ (test/server/server.test.js:238:45)
      at tryCatch (node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:65:40)
      at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:303:22)
      at Generator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:117:21)
      at step (test/server/server.test.js:7:191)
      at test/server/server.test.js:7:361
```

Packages being used:

```
"babel-jest": "^23.4.0"
"@types/jest": "^23.3.0"
"jest": "^23.4.1"
"jest-enzyme": "^6.0.2"
"jest-transform-graphql": "^2.1.0"
```

It's weird because I'm using that very same matcher in other files and it **works just fine**, for instance:

```
it("should return all templates for a Postgres datasource", () => {
    const templates = getTemplatesForDataSource(
        { type: DataSourceType.Postgres }
    );

    expect(templates).toMatchObject({
        requestMappingTemplates: {
            Custom: "",
            "Postgres Query": expect.any(String)
        },
        responseMappingTemplates: {
            Custom: "",
            "Postgres Response": expect.any(String)
        }
    });
});
```

Any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

`fetch.data.items[0]` does not have a prototype. My guess is that under the hood jest's `toMatchObject` requires a prototype and fails. I can see that there is an issue filed with Jest about it that you have "thumbs upped": https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/6730

In the meantime you can use Jest's `toEqual` matcher. It does not require the objects to have prototypes.

Comment: Fair point using .toEqual, I missed something in my code that makes .toMatchObject needed tho. I have other fields in fetch.data.items[0] that I don't want to check for equality. I will update my post sorry for confusion.